# Adding Provisioning profile to JDeveloper - mobile app

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am trying to develop a Hello World application and run it on my iphone. I have successfully created the project etc. but i end up getting the following error. How can i add the provisioning profile to JDeveloper ?

```
Cannot deploy iOS application to an archive or iTunes because the signature or provisioning profile is missing.
```

EDIT

I also went to JDeveloper --> Tools --> ADF mobile --> Platform --> (select ios) --> browsed to the location where i have installed the provisioning profile.

There is also a text field here that says; `Certificate`. What should i add here ?

- MAC OS 10.7.2

Comment: hmm... i think the forum in not active.

Comment: Do you have an iOS Developer account from Apple? You'll need to add your developer key in order to deploy to an actual iOS device. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/deploying.htm#CHDIJDGE

Comment: The jdev forum is one of the active forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting video about ADF Mobile for iOS:
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adfmobiledeployios.html

You should find all the deployed info there.